# Interactive Java Program

Tags: java

```
    double hourlyrateofpay ;
   int numberofhoursworked ;
   double moneymade = hourlyrateofpay * numberofhoursworked;

   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your hourly rate of pay");
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of hours worked");
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You worked \t" + numberofhoursworked + "\t"                         
  + "hours" +"with an hourly rate of pay \t" + hourlyrateofpay + " and    
   made\t" + moneymade);
```

What is wrong with this code? ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: `"What is wrong with this code?"` -- You tell us -- what error messages or misbehaviors are you getting if any? Note, please avoid posting code that is indented so much as to be hard to read. I tried to fix it.

Comment: the compiler errors should give you enough clues

Answer (score 1):

You ignore the results returned from your JOptionPane calls. Put those results into a variable.

Note

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Foo");
```

but

```
String foo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Foo");
```

or

```
String foo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter some int");
int someInt = Integer.parseInt(foo);
```

You also appear to be trying to do your calculations **before** getting your user input. That should intuitively not make sense to you, right?